# Do not allow detach for one bash

Tags: bash, process, container

I would like to know if it's possible to forbid all detached-like things for a given shell.

More precisely, I'd like to make sure that if a `command` runs in a specific shell, when the `command` stops, all the children spawn by that command are deleted, no matter what `command` does (including running a new screen, detach...). That way, I want to make sure that if the command:

```
ps -O stat --ppid <my bash ppid>
```

does not output anything, then there is no remaining process on my computer ran by a given user.

Is it possible without using containers?

Comment: I have the same question. My purpose is to be able to control the process' watch its subprocesses and kill them all at any time. Currently it is a big deal to dig what does my program spawned!